# jquery prepend uncaught typeerror object has no method prepend

Tags: jquery, methods, append, prepend

we're working on a site:
[www.granthammond.com](http://granthammond.com)
that features an IDX plugin, which outputs a lot or dynamic flavor on the search result pages, 
http://granthammond.com/idx/mls-1385061-8788_highway_70_nashville_tn_37221

i'm using some jQuery to move some of the DOM around, specifically, the `#source-ordered-content` and the `#dsidx-disclaimer`, 
i'm using `.remove` and `.prepend`, 
i'm getting the error:
`uncaught typeerror, object has no method .prepend`
odd. i'm pretty sure i've done this sort of thing before, but i'm not doing it right this time, obviously, and my jQuery skills are out to lunch, apparently.

here's the horror, er, code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// do_stuff
var socHeight;
var socDiv;
var socContent;
var dsidxDisclaimer;

// get height of source ordered content
socHeight = $("#source-ordered-content").height();
wrapHeight = $("#wrap").height();

//console.log( 'socHeight: ' + socHeight );
//console.log( 'wrapHeight: ' + socHeight );

$("#content").css({
     'height': socHeight
});

// or, for IDX data pages, 

socContent = $(".page-dsidxpress-data #source-ordered-content").remove();
$("#content").prepend(socContent);

//move the disclaimer down into the footer.
dsidxDisclaimer = $(".page-dsidxpress-data #dsidx-disclaimer").remove();
$("#footer").append(dsidxDisclaimer);

}); // end (document).ready()
```

thanks again stack.

Answer (score 0):

You're using it wrong.

What you're appending and prepending with your current code is not the element but the removal of the element, which wont work. I dont say this is working code (since you didn't provide a jsfiddle), but it should go down something like this:

```
socContent = $(".page-dsidxpress-data #source-ordered-content")
socContent.remove();
$("#content").prepend(socContent);

//move the disclaimer down into the footer.
dsidxDisclaimer = $(".page-dsidxpress-data #dsidx-disclaimer");
dsidxDisclaimer.remove();
$("#footer").append(dsidxDisclaimer);
```

Comment: well, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k32KX/, it works in the fiddle, but not on the site.

Comment: Then I think something else is wrong on your page. Have you tried debugging the page? Probably something wrong either on the positioning of the script or syntax error.